# what does the --enable-threads=LIB when compiling gcc/g++/libstdc++ means?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, g++

http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/libstdc++-2.90.8/html/configopts.html , the option is explained there , does it mean , that stl is thread safe , and is it that way by default ?

Comment: As I read the text in the link, it has nothing to do with thread safety, but what underlying threading system should be used.

Comment: As above I would leave it well alone, assume the standard objects are multiread, single write. If multithread setup some std::mutexs.

Answer (score 5):

Read the fabulous manual, and read a recent version on the official GCC website, not some 12 year old copy of the docs that refers to an ancient version! The current documentation for `--enable-threads` is at http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html and the documentation explaining whether libstdc++ is thread-safe is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html#manual.intro.using.concurrency.thread_safety

You'll get a better answer by referring to the official docs than asking on SO and hoping you get answers from people who actually know what they're talking about.

1) The option you're asking about only affects GCC, so it obviously only affects GCC's standard library, it says nothing about thread safety in the stl in general.

2) Most C++03 library implementations (including GCC's) and all C++11 library implementations follow the definition of thread safety used by the SGI implementation of the STL: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html

3) As explained in that documentation, GCC's standard library is always "thread safe" if you follow simple rules about not accessing objects from multiple threads, `--enable-threads` doesn't affect that.  What it affects is (as mentioned in a comment above) the underlying multithreading API that is used to implement the internal mutexes and threading features needed internally by libstdc++.  On **almost all** platforms the only supported options will be `--enable-threads=single` (equivalent to `--disable-threads`) or the native thread model (e.g. on POSIX platforms `--enable-threads=posix`, on Windows `--enable-threads=win32`) so you probably do **not** want to use that option, just let GCC choose the default value for your platform.